# Using jQuery to add css depending on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser

I am using `jQuery.css("background", "coolGradient code")`.

I either need to:

1. add multiple lines of `"background"` to cover all the browser prefixes
   (I can't figure out how to do this) or
2. detect the browser and add the correct background css code.

EDIT: I tried doing something like the below, but I think every new line is replacing the one before it.

```
$(".lighter-grad").css({"background": "-webkit-linear-gradient(code)",
"background": "-moz-linear-gradient(code)"})
```

Comment: can u provide with uptill now what you have done...a sample code or a fiddle....

Comment: Added an example of what I've tried"

Answer (score 0):

For example with IE:

```
/msie/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent) && $("div").css({"background": "red"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use .addClass()/.removeClass methods? Like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/5gdh7xtc/

Code:

```
$('.test-div')
    .removeClass('background-original')
    .addClass('background-with-prefixes');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your code...

```
$(".lighter-grad").css("background", "-webkit-linear-gradient(code)");
$(".lighter-grad").css("background", "-moz-linear-gradient(code)");
```

this is the correct syntax.

let me know if it worked.

Comment: Yes, that works. I didn't know I had to split it up.